# PPC emulator to run Tiger

Tags: software-recommendation, games, macos, classic-mac-os

This might seem like an odd request: There are some classic and early OSX apps which I really enjoyed using and I would like to revive. Is there an emulator which can run the versions of MacOSX Tiger created to run on computers with PPC architecture?

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to emulate PowerPC for Mac OS 9.2.2 through 10.5 via QEMU: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/GuestOperatingSystems/MacOS10.4 and https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/PowerPC.

You'll need to install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), a package manager for Mac OS X/OS X/macOS. Then run `brew install qemu` (which already contains the PowerPC part).

To create the a hard disk image, run

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 example.img 100M
```

replacing

- `example.img` with the path you want to store your disk image in
- `100M` with the size you want (at least 3.0GB to install Tiger according to Apple, probably about 10GB to be safe).

<sub>You could also use a sparse (bundle) disk image with QEMU (you'll then be able to natively mount it within the host) but that requires a bit of setup and a script.</sub>

You can run then Tiger with

```
qemu-system-ppc -L pc-bios -boot d -M mac99 -m 512 -hda example.img \
    -cdrom <iso file of installation media> \
    -netdev user,id=mynet0 -device sungem,netdev=mynet0 `
```

where  is the ISO of a Tiger install disk (you could also use the disk directly as well as dmg images using the same method for a sparsebundle)

Comment: How would you go about downloading the necessary files and installing ?

Comment: @NoahM I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd install an Intel version of Mac OS X 10.5-10.6 in a virtual machine and use it to run PowerPC apps thru [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)). Intel version of Tiger 10.4.4 might be possible to install too, but I only tried 10.5 and 10.6.

If you really need to emulate PowerPC version of Tiger, there's [PearPC](https://github.com/sebastianbiallas/pearpc) project: